# Flutter Location won't print to console

Tags: flutter

I'm new to learning flutter and am learning about the flutter location package.I have declared a function that can be called on the press of a button. The function has to print latitude and longitude to the console. Can you tell me where I went wrong as nothing is getting printed on the console.

Code:

```
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoadingScreen> createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  void getLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
    LocationData locationData;
    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }
    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    locationData = await location.getLocation();
    print("${locationData.latitude}, ${locationData.longitude}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: getLocation,
          child: const Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have granted the permission 'always allow when using this app'.
location version: 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

If your are runing your app on Android device you should add

< uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

to your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

To debug, you can include a print statement before the return statement to see if the function returns one of two cases.
Example:

```dart
 void getLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
    LocationData locationData;
    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();

      /// add this
      print("$serviceEnabled");

      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }
    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();

      /// add this
      print("$permissionGranted");

      if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    locationData = await location.getLocation();
    print("${locationData.latitude}, ${locationData.longitude}");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

tested your code, and works fine.

after you install the package Location, remember that you have to add for ios in info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need location.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need location.</string>
```

and on android, in manifest.xml:

```
<manifest>

...
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

...

</manifest>
```

finally, remember that you have to **restart the app**